# I have multipe dropdown list in a html form, now i have to store selected values to database using coldfusion

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have multiple drop down list in a html form, now i have to store selected values to database using cold fusion. I am facing problem in storing list values to CFM variables.

```
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function set_month(){
            var str='';
            for (i=0;i<s1.length;i++) { 
            if(s1[i].selected){
                // Here i want to do something like
                <CFSET FORM.months=s1[i]>
                str +=s1[i].value + "<br >"; 
              }
            } 
            document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML=str;
            return true;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <select id=s1 name=no_year onChange="set_month()"; multiple size=4>
        <option value=Jan>January</option>
        <option value=February>February</option>
        <option value=March>March</option>
        <option value=April>April</option>
        <option value=June>June</option>
        <option value=Jul>July</option>
        <option value=Auguest>Auguest</option>
        <option value=September>Septembr</option>
        <option value=October>October</option>
        <option value=November>November</option>
        <option value=December>December</option>
    </select>
    <div id='msg3'><br><br></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I read comments already. Can you please explain what's the specific problem in description.

Comment: And what you did to improve your question?

Comment: @HemantPandey your post needs to be a specific question that can be answered objectively with code. You must provide proof that you have actually tried something before we can help you.

Comment: Added code snippet.

Comment: Your JavaScript code is wrong. You cannot use CF tags in JavaScript code and expect them to run on the client.

Comment: How can I access list values on server side using cold fusion ?

Comment: Step 1 - submit the form to a ColdFusion page.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other members pointed out, you can't have your CF tags inside the javascript block and you need to have a `<form>` tag along with a "Submit" button, to have the form variables which can then be used in executing a CFQuery.

You can write the save logic like this,

```
<cfif IsDefined('form.submit')>
    <cfquery datasource="your_dsn_name">
        INSERT INTO tblSelectedMonths (month_name) 
        VALUES ( <cfqueryparam value="#form.no_year#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> )
    </cfquery >
</cfif>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="s1">Select preferences : </label>
            <select id="s1" name="no_year" multiple size="4">
                <option value="Jan">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="Jul">July</option>
                <option value="Auguest">Auguest</option>
                <option value="September">Septembr</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="November">November</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Note: You need to change the datasource, tablename according to your environment/settings in the above example

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the edits!.. The above example was an abstract one. Just wanted to  give him a basic idea regarding what needs to be done. I'll follow up the coding practices going further